# Can we supervise on the hidden states of RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to generate some history-dependent model with machine learning, whose underline physical model has a clear definition of its "internal state variable" (a state derived from historical inputs) and how this variable interacts with the inputs to get the outputs. Mathematically this reads: $y_t=f(x_t,h_t)$, $h_t=g(x_1, ..., x_{t-1})$ .

Intuitively, this can be realized by RNN(or LSTM/GRU). Now I wonder if we can add the supervision on state variables to the loss function to improve prediction. For instance, we extract the hidden states $H$ output from our RNN and pass them through another branch of feed-forward network to predict the internal state variables $h$. The loss function then has two parts, one is for model outputs $\sum (y-\hat{y})^2$, and the other is for model internal states $\sum(h-\hat{h})^2$.

Any insight toward the following questions are welcomed:

- Will this approach work? (Does it make sense?)
- Potential issues?

I'll also be really grateful if anybody can indicate closely related works in the answers! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples of performing supervision on hidden states for history dependent models.

**Latent variables**

Loss functions are commonly applied to internal states such as latent variables in *variational autoencoders* (VAEs).

**Hidden states**

Supervision **directly on hidden states**, as opposed to latent states in RNNs, has been performed for imposing sparsity, as in [[1](https://www2.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/wtm/publications/2019/YWH19/ICANN2019_202_final_v4.pdf)]:

> In order to impose sparsity, we introduce an L1-norm loss term over
> the output gate at layer $l$ as
>
> $$\mathcal{L}^S(o^l(x,\theta)) = \sum_{1 \leq b \leq B} \sum_{1 \leq
> > t\leq T} | o_t^l(x^{(b)})|.$$

**Autoregressive Neural Networks**

Additional, *auxilliary latent variables* have been used to increase the flexibility of variational inference. An example of this is given in [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04934)] where hidden state $\mathbf{h}$ and latent state $\mathbf{z}_{t-1}$ are fed into an autoregressive neural network, with final output $\mathbf{z}_t$.

## Reference

[1](https://www2.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/wtm/publications/2019/YWH19/ICANN2019_202_final_v4.pdf) Learning Sparse Hidden States in Long Short-Term Memory, [(paper)](https://www2.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/wtm/publications/2019/YWH19/ICANN2019_202_final_v4.pdf)

[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04934) Improved Variational Inference with Inverse Autoregressive Flow, [(arxiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04934)

Answer (score 1):

Your physical model looks dubious.  It is a bit unusual and might not be a perfect match for a RNN/LSTM.  I am hoping that your physical model is actually $y_t=f(x_t,h_t)$, $h_t=g(x_{t-1},h_{t-1})$.  If so, then this is a good fit for the kind of supervision on internal states that you plan to do -- and the answer to your question is yes, you can do this, and it is a sensible thing to do.